# Playbook has SSH issues in AWX 23.0.0

Tags: ansible-awx

I have some playbooks running without any issues in AWX 9.0.1.0 and currently I am working on moving all the playbooks to newer version AWX 23.0.0.

When I run the playbook in AWX 23.0.0 GUI, it always fails, giving some SSH related errors, the related SSH command used by playbook looks something like

bash-5.1$ ssh -vvv -F ./ssh.cfg -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="test"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -W %h:%p -q test@jump.test.net' -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'ControlPath="~/.ssh/ansible-%r@%h:%p"' test.net

When I copied this SSH command above into AWX task container and directly execute this SSH command , it is running success, so clearly the SSH public/private key set up is correct, also I am sure the credential to be configured in AWX has correctly imported the related SSH private key.

So I am confused now what else can be the cause

The key error logs are

```
      `  Authenticated to test.net (via proxy) using \"publickey\".\r\n

        debug1: pkcs11_del_provider: called, provider_id = (null)\r\n

        debug1: setting up multiplex master socket\r\n

        debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /runner/.ssh/ansible-test@test.net:22.pqGv0YsDRO3Skadp\r\n

        unix_listener: cannot bind to path /runner/.ssh/ansible-test@test.net:22.pqGv0YsDRO3Skadp: No such file or directory",
        "unreachable": true
```

`
It is weird that the user listed above is 'ansible-test', but I have never configured this user anywhere in my platform, the real user should be 'test'

Any suggestion is welcome

If anyone knows how to directly upgrade from AWX 9.0.1.0 to  AWX 23.0.0, that would be even better, although it seems not that possible as AWX 23.0.0 is running on K8S while  AWX 9.0.10 is running on Docker

Comment: I have fixed this issue temporarily with some assistance from AWX community. The 'ansible-' prefix is from the ansible.cfg file and the error is related to the control master feature, which I have disabled for the time being. After these two changes, my playbook is running smoothly.